# specifying a file in a classpathresource

Tags: java, spring, jar, log4j, classpath

I am using `classpathresource` to get the resource of a file . In my code am specifying the path so that the file is picked from there . But its taking a file with same name which is already there in a jar from previous.

i.e.,
I have specified,

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/sw/merlot/config/log4j.xml")
```

where `log4j.xml` is the configuration file.

But its taking a `log4j.xml` which is in a jar -- `sw/merlot/lib/keyManager.jar!/log4j.xml`

(Both `log4j.xml` are different [2 different configuration files])

So i changed it to,

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("file:///sw/merlot/config/log4j.xml")
```

But its still not working .

I dont know if the way I have specified the file is correct or not?

I also tried to specify the file using a jar .

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("jar:file:///sw/merlot/lib/keyManager111.jar!/log4j.xml")
```

where `keyManager111.jar` contains my `log4j.xml` which i want. But its still not picking from the jar. Its telling file not found at the specified location.

Comment: Just creating a `ClassPathResource` doesn't do anything on its own.  What are you doing with it?

Comment: Am getting the resource for the specified file and using it as an inputstream for some other process.

Comment: I would try to go a step back, and remove log4j.xml from the library. As a rule of thumb, no library should include logging configuration, that's the responsibility of the client. (I'm assuming you own KeyManager.jar)

Comment: +1 for Augusto. If the library really needs its own log4j.xml, then just don't put yours in the same package. Packages exist precisely to avoid name clashes (for classes as for other resources).

Comment: You still haven't shown us *what* you are trying to do with the `ClasspathResource`

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:/sw/merlot/config/log4j.xml");
```

or if it is in a different jar file:

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath*:/sw/merlot/config/log4j.xml");
```